# show some locations as circles or points (not pushpins) on a map based on OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, openstreetmap

I would like to show some locations on a map.

I use XAML MAP control (https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/) to show some locations on a map based on OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013 WPF.

But, I would like to show the locations as points or circles not as pushpin.

In (https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/) MainWinwow.xaml, I found:

```
<Path map:MapPanel.Location="53.5,8.2" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="#1F007F00">
    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" Transform="{Binding ScaleTransform, ElementName=map}"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

But, how to do do this in MainWinwow.xaml.cs because I need to load the locations from a file.

Comment: There is a sample application in the download package that shows how to do this with a MapItemsControl. It displays a collection of points from a view model class. But note that it will of course not be capable of displaying your 0.5 million points.

Comment: @Clements, if I want to show 30k points, how to do this by C# code not by XAML ? I need to load the locations from a file.

Comment: Well, take a look at the sample application. However, you won't be satisfied by the performance. 30k points is just to much to be displayed as individual UI elements.

Comment: Who on earth needs to see 30k points at one time anyway? Certainly there's a more appropriate method of UX to convey the desired result.